# Call module method from other class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So i have one ruby file that is reside inside model > service

```
module Services

   module SomeJobs


    def mainJob
   ... 
    end
  end
end
```

and how do i call that method from ruby class that sit inside lib/testfunction.rb

I tried the following and it did not work. any help is appreciate. I am trying to debug the code.

```
class TestFunction
  include SomeJobs

  TestFunction::mainJob
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out

```
module Services    
   module SomeJobs    
    def self.mainJob
    end
  end
end
```

make mainJob a module method, as module instance method are never included in the   including class, they are private to module

```
class TestFunction
  include Services::SomeJobs
end
```

now call from

outside this TestFunction class like

```
TestFunction.new.mainJob
```

and inside this TestFunction class with

```
self.class.new.mainJob
```

if you want to access mainJob as class method then, use extend instead of include.

as you are using IDE debugger

try requiring that file relative to rails application, in your

TestFunction Class

Comment: I got this error
uninitialized constant TestFunction::Services (NameError)

Comment: @JitenK does this service module is located in app/models?

Comment: this service module located inside app/model/services and this one is extended by one of the model

Comment: @JitenK try including it in TestFunction class with

'include ::Services::SomeJobs'